# Geography Markup Language rendering on Android

Tags: android, svg, opengl-es, gml-geographic-markup-lan

Can I use Open GL ES or some graphics engine to render GML's on Android. Or else transformation from GML to SVG is necessary for using it in Open GL ES or some graphics Engine.

Comment: I'm interested in that question. Have you found any solution to that problem?